# Image inside ImageView is showing really blurry

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to develop a little android app, that will use image recognition for dog breeds. After recognizing a dog, it will save in another activity the name of the breed, with a picture. Those are saved in a MaterialCardView, which has inside a Linearlayout, with an ImageView for the picture, a TextView and an ImageButton for delete. In the preview window, everything looks fine:
[Preview Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAyRU.png)
,but when I'm testing on my phone the Image is verry blurred, or very zoomed in, I don't even know how to describe it:
[Actual app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDgt7.png).
I tried with many pictures, also tried most of the solutions that I saw online, but nothing worked. I'm also a begginer with android, so it might be something very simple that I just can't see.
Here is the xml code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        >


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/affenpinscher"
                android:id="@+id/img_content"

            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txv_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                />
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibt_delete"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                />


    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Also tried with android:scaleType="centerCrop" or just "center", it's the same.
The Image is 220x330

Comment: scaleType=“centerInside” , if it doesn’t work correctly, change imageView width and height by wrap_content instead of 150dp

Comment: @daniel.jbatiz I changed it to scaleType=“centerInside” and it didn't even show the image anymore, and when I changed with wrap_content, it scales around the text, looking like this: https://imgur.com/a/e7iAhAJ

Comment: How are you setting the imageSource to the imageView?. There is a great image handler library called Picasso, that could be the solution to your problem

Comment: for now the source is set into the xml with android:src="@drawable/affenpinscher" as a test image, and later when I populate the list with the right images, I thought about using something like `itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_content).setImageResource(R.drawable.affenpinscher)`. I never heard about Picasso, gonna have a look at it

Comment: First of all , try using another image as test to disscard an image problem. If that behavior persists no worry for now, use Picasso when youre are going to populate the list. https://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I tried with around 10 diffrent images, only one worked, witch is the one used for the ImageButton too, and I think it worked because it is only 48x48

Comment: Install an Android Studio plugin called Android Drawable Importer, once installed and restarted the IDE, in your drawable folder right click and select new-> Batch import and add the image

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like the resolution was too big, the Android Drawable Importer solved it. It's kinda sad that I will have to do this for 120 pictures(for each breed) but I found no other solution

Comment: Post the answer and approve it.

Comment: Flavius Biras , you can approve the posted answer to help anyone in the same situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is blurry because has a bigger resolution than supported for the imageView with its current size.

So you got to resize the image.
Go to the IDE settings -> Plugins -> Search “ Android Drawable Importer and install it -> restart the IDE 
Once installed right click the drawable folder and: New-> Batch Drawable Import -> select your image and resize it.